# asp.net mvc internationalization automation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, internationalization, automation

Is any tools for automation in internationalization for mvc exist? I need to internationalize web solution now. it wasn't implemented any features for internationalization there. All content are hard coded mostly (I mean view texts, messages and so on). Maybe some one could advice something that will be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately with MVC we don't have the benefit of Visual Studio's "Generate Local Resources" command (available in the Tools menu when a Web Form is open), which does just what you need.  So unless someone wrote a tool for this, you are stuck with copying your text to resources manually.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any tools that might help you if everything is hardcoded. I would recommend you the [following guide](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html).

Comment: actually I know how to do that. But it really boring work to create all resources by hands and copy information from view to them. So I hope that it possible to automate somehow

Comment: @Ph0en1x, I understand your pain and I completely share it with you. Unfortunately you realize that such a tool would be very hard to create as it wouldn't really know what strings in your code is intended to be internationalized. That's up to you and it will depend on your particular scenario, don't you agree?

Comment: yeah. Ofcoure it's impossible to automate it 100% but i think that some parts could be automate.